# searching custom property in user profile

Tags: 2013

I created a custom property in the user profile. I want to search through all the user profiles and output those profiles in which the custom property contains a certain string

For example:

User1- Custom Property value is 1,2,3

User2- Custom Property value in 2,4,5

User3- Custom Property value is 4,6,8

I want to output all the profiles in which Custom Property contains "2"

(using c# code)

So the output should have User1 and User2

Can someone suggest the best way to implement this? I did find some links in the internet for searching user profiles use KeyWord search but and not sure if those methods could be used to search through Custom Properties. Example: https://www.collaboris.com/how-to-use-search-keywordquery-to-query-user-profiles-in-sharepoint/

I am using SharePoint 2013

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I posted answer to the same question which I had posted in stack overflow:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43853060/search-custom-property-in-sharepoint-user-profile/43923567